# Django AllAuth KeyError at /accounts/signup/ 'sociallogin'

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-allauth

I am using Django All Auth for the first time. I have set up all the urls. I haven't setup any social network provider. The login works, but when I click on the signup it comes up with the exception:

**KeyError at /accounts/signup/** 
**'sociallogin'**

[image]

I am also trying to make the Firstname and Last name compulsory on the regular SignUp (not the Social Login). Is my *forms.py* correct?

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='First Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Last Name')
    
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')        
    
    def save(self, request):
        user = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
```

My All Auth Settings

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 7
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = False
ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEMBER = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL = LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL  = None
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT = 5
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_TIMEOUT = 300
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_BLACKLIST = ['admin', 'superuser', 'user']
```

I didn't change anything in the *ACCOUNT_FORMS* dictionary. Its the default.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue as well and surprisingly seems like an expectation thing with the code.

This is how I solved it for now -

```
import types

empty_user = types.SimpleNamespace()
empty_user.user = types.SimpleNamespace()
empty_user.user.email = ""
empty_user.user.username = ""
empty_user.user.first_name = ""
empty_user.user.last_name = ""
social_signup = SocialSignupForm(sociallogin=empty_user)
```

I'll also look into reporting this as an issue.